# Highlight of the current open file in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to highlight the current file open selected for edition in VSCode?
Some themes show a underline in diferent color. But I want that caractheristic in the default theme

[image]

Comment: the tabcolor of the active tab is different, you can increase the contrast by choosing a different color, also the active tab has the `x` always visible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify any themes for Visual Studio Code.

1. Open the `settings.json` file.

- Open the command palette using <kbd>F1</kbd>
- Type "*open user settings json*"

2. Add the following parameters in the opened file:

   "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
   "tab.activeBorderTop": "yourColor"
   }
3. Save the changes

[image]

P.S. You could see in the attached screenshot that the color of the top border in my active tab already changed.
You could find many different options to modify visual stuff.